# php mysql sum issue

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I want to generate a report to accumulate the total stock quantity that has been ordered by different branches in a month, and each branch will sum up the quantity by merged (GROUP BY) stock.

i trimmed up my database table for easy understanding as below:

```
Item     Branch        Order_Quantity
---------------------------------------
Pencil   Branch-A         5
Ruler    Branch-D         3
Staple   Branch-C         12
Pencil   Branch-A         5
Ruler    Branch-B         3
Staple   Branch-C         2
Pencil   Branch-A         10
Ruler    Branch-A         6
Staple   Branch-D         1
```

for example, below is draft of expected outcome result:

```
Item     Branch-A     Branch-B     Branch-C     Branch-D
----------------------------------------------------------
Pencil     20            15           32           8
Ruler      12            0            40           10
Staple     4             8             5           0
```

and so on...

How can I use query to call the above result and assign each sum to their respective branch column?

below is my query:

```
SELECT `Item`, `Branch`, sum(`Order_Quantity`) FROM `table` GROUP BY `Item`
```

but when I call and loop the table, the result will show sum quantity to every branches

```
Item     Branch-A     Branch-B     Branch-C     Branch-D
----------------------------------------------------------
Pencil     75            75           75           75
Ruler      62            62           62           62
Staple     17            17           17           17
```

Hope someone can help for this.

thanks.

Comment: what exactly are you "loop"ing? You need to paste in your php because there's nothing in your sql that would generate separate columns of branches as you have them displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some kind of PIVOT:

```
select item, 
    sum(case when branch = 'Branch-A' then order_Quantity else 0 end) as BranchA,
    sum(case when branch = 'Branch-B' then order_Quantity else 0 end) as BranchB,
    sum(case when branch = 'Branch-C' then order_Quantity else 0 end) as BranchC,
    sum(case when branch = 'Branch-D' then order_Quantity else 0 end) as BranchD
from yourTable
group by item
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT `Item`, `Branch`, sum(`Order_Quantity`) FROM `table` GROUP BY `Item`, `Branch`
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have a finite number of branches you can create a query with sub selects for each "column" you wish to display (as per branch) with your sums, like so...

```
select 
  (select sum(order_quantity) from table where branch = 'Branch-A'),
  (select sum(order_quantity) from table where branch = 'Branch-B'),
```

etc..

This is not a very elegant solution, but it will result in what you're looking for.

Otherwise you can follow the advice of the other posters which is more efficient from a sql standpoint but will not generate the columns you are hoping to see (as per your question).

Comment: Why do You used LIKE if string is a full match?

Comment: force of habit. Always compare strings with like and numbers with =. For me it's just easier to look at. I'm not sure if there's any efficiency loss, if there is, I've never heard of it.

Comment: @DrDredel it uses regular expressions, that so it's not a good habit to compare with LIKE when You needn't LIKE

Comment: @EgorSazanovich, huh... ok, good to know, thanks! (I edited my answer, though I still think my approach is a terrible one, and is only "right" in that it addresses the specific request of the OP.

Comment: @DrDredel sometimes You need a fast solution, not strict, but fast ;) Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Order_Quantity) AS CNT FROM `table` GROUP BY `Branch`;
```